# Clone an array and make it unique - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, copy, javascript-objects

I have a problem. I have an array of objects. I need to make a copy out of it and make it unique, so when I modify my new array, it doesn't change anything in the original one.

I have tried the following:

```
let excelData = [...this.state.tableData]; 
let excelData = this.state.tableData.slice();
let excelData = this.state.tableData.concat();
let excelData = Array.from(this.state.tableData);
```

But all of the previously listed methods also modify the original array.

Here is my function:

```
addDynamicExcelColumns() {
        let excelData = [...this.state.tableData];
        if (this.state.compRentAttr.length > 0) {
            excelData.map((d, idx) => {
                this.state.compRentAttr.map((i, idx1) => {
                    excelData[idx][i.AttrName] = d.optionalAttributes[idx1];
                });
            });
        }
        return excelData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are just making a new array with same elements.
when you do `let excelData = [...this.state.tableData];`, `excelData[index]` is equal to `this.state.tableData[index]`

So, what you need to do is a deep clone.
And it's not a perfect way to deep clone, but it looks like you can just use `let excelData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.tableData));`.